# How to switch form1 and form2 by each button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a new form called form2.

I try to new form2 on form1 init function.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace c_charp_multiform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Form2 form2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

I can success show the form2, but I fail to press a button to switch to form1, because form2 doesn't has any instance of form1.

How could I change back by a button on form2?

Here is the form2 code now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace c_charp_multiform
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            //Don't know what to do next
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much~

Comment: I have already let form1 disappear before by pressing a button to show form2. So I can't click on Form1.

Comment: I want to achieve an interactive way to switch forms like game.

Comment: has my example worked for you or do you want it in another way ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you~ I solve this problem by your method. I will try to post my full working code later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass Form1 to Form2 like this.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 m_frm

    public Form2(Form1 frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_frm = frm;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        m_frm.Show();
        m_frm.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace c_charp_multiform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //要建立form2的變數，這樣才能產生能夠傳參數的form
        private Form2 form2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //將form1隱藏
            this.Visible = false;
            //將form2給new出來，new的同時將自己的記憶體位置傳給form2
            //這樣到時候form2要切換回form1前就可以先設定要顯示form1
            form2 = new Form2(this);
            //顯示form2
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace c_charp_multiform
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Form1 m_form1;
        //在建立form2時得到form1的記憶體位置，
        //這樣之後就可以改form1的參數，也就是將form1顯示出來
        public Form2(Form1 p_form1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //將form1的記憶體位址存起來
            m_form1 = p_form1;
        }

        /***
         * 這個按鈕的主要供能是將form2切換回form1
         **/
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //將form2隱藏
            this.Visible = false;
            //顯示form1
            m_form1.Visible = true;
            //關閉form2
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //顯示form1
            //加這行的主要目的是避免使用者在form2時就將form2直接關閉，
            //而不是按了切換回form1的按鈕後才關閉，
            //因此這樣就會導致了form1還在隱藏而沒有被關閉的情況發生，但是也無法被控制。
            //以寫程式來說，再次編寫程式就會編譯失敗
            //以執行面來說，就會有多餘的process佔著cpu和記憶體空間，不划算。
            m_form1.Visible = true;
            //此時就可以關閉form1，當然沒有將form1切回visible也可以關閉，
            //只是少了form1跳出立刻消失的關閉動畫~XD
            m_form1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```